# Java: Why parallel stream works slow at the start of application?

Tags: java, performance, parallel-processing, java-stream, startup

I decided to measure performance difference between regular stream and parallel stream on Java 1.8.045, CPU: AMD a10-6800k 4-Cores x64:
If I put parallel stream before sequential stream, it works slowly than sequential stream.
I suspect that first stream in base code work slow anyway.
 I decided that problem is that JVM starting takes time. I even put Thread.sleep(100000) at the start of base code. It does not help. 
If I put first sequential stream, and second is parallel stream - everything looks correct, but ... :) 
**To test parallel stream vs regular stream were planned**: load 6M text file, count amount of words which size is more then 12 symbols.
I do it by two separated streams and I measure performance for each of them.
To exclude any unnecessary influence:

1. I load file twice into two separated ArrayLists(every array list for particular stream).
2. I load data by old Java method to exclude any influence from this side.
3. I even put Strings into String pool.
4. I raised -Xms and -Xmx : VM options:
   -verbose:gc -Xms1000000k -Xmx3000000k
   **I don't get** : [GC (Allocation Failure)  65536K->9238K(251392K), 0.0085762 secs]

If I put parallel stream first, I get:
*Parallel stream duration: 287.271699

Words count by parallel stream : 7588

Regular stream duration: 138.9853

Words count by regular stream : 7588*

Parallel stream duration is more than regular stream duration almost in 2 times.

If I put regular stream first, I get:
*Regular stream duration: 336.4724

Words count by regular stream : 7588

Parallel stream duration: 98.5675

Words count by parallel stream : 7588*

I understand that JVM could be starting it should be Hot and I should do measuring several times.
Yes, If I put first Stream into cycle and do calculation several times in the same process, first calculation is slow, second calculation is faster.
I guess it is normal to expect stable behaviour of parrallel stream at the start of JVM as well.
Is there other influence exept of GC on performance at the start of application?
Why it happens? We use different collections. Why first stream calculation in base code is slow at any time?

**My base code:**

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class StreamsExperiment {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        try(BufferedReader bufferedReaderParallel = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("resource//war_and_peace.txt"))){
            String line = bufferedReaderParallel.readLine();
            ArrayList<String> lineListParallel = new ArrayList<>();
            while (line != null) {
                line.intern();
                lineListParallel.add(line);
                line = bufferedReaderParallel.readLine();
            }
            long startTimeParallel =  System.nanoTime();
            long bigWordsCount2 = lineListParallel.stream().parallel().flatMap(x -> Pattern.compile("\\PL+").splitAsStream(x)).filter(w -> w.length() > 12).count();
            long stopTimeParallel = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println("Parallel stream duration: " + (stopTimeParallel - startTimeParallel) / 1000000.0);
            System.out.println("Words count by parallel stream : " + bigWordsCount2);
        } catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("I/O error : " + e);
        }

        try(BufferedReader bufferedReaderRegular = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("resource//war_and_peace.txt"))){
            String line = bufferedReaderRegular.readLine();
            ArrayList<String> lineListRegular = new ArrayList<>();
            while (line != null) {
                line.intern();
                lineListRegular.add(line);
                line = bufferedReaderRegular.readLine();
            }
            long startTimeRegular =  System.nanoTime();
            long bigWordsCount1 = lineListRegular.stream().flatMap(x -> Pattern.compile("\\PL+").splitAsStream(x)).filter(w -> w.length() > 12).count();
            long stopTimeRegular = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println("Regular stream duration: " + (stopTimeRegular - startTimeRegular) / 1000000.0);
            System.out.println("Words count by regular stream : " + bigWordsCount1);
        } catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("I/O error : " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really related to the problem but shouldn't `Pattern.compile("\\PL+")` be defines as a variable? Compiling it for every single record might have some impact on performance as well.

Comment: What happens when you try to run those blocks of code many times (10+)? And try running them alternately.

Comment: If I run process several times, I get the same results. If I put parallel stream calculation into cycle, and regular stream calculation into separated cycle,  the first calculation of parallel stream in first iteration is slow, second iteration of parallel calculation is faster then first calculation of parallel stream and any calculations of regular stream.

Comment: This is not how performance is to be measured. Please take a look at [Microbenchmarking with JMH](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/)

Comment: I defined Pattern.compile("\\PL+") as separate variable. It does not help.
I changed the basecode corresponding to this.

Comment: To demonstrate how nonsensical your “benchmark” is, just swap the two tests, doing sequential first and parallel then. Besides that, I recommend to learn about [`Files.readAllLines(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-) ant, well, since the reading is not part of your benchmark, why are you doing it twice instead of re-using the list? And the `line.intern();` call makes no sense at all, it’s wasting CPU cycles for nothing.

Comment: Since you already noted yourself that it is always the *first* Stream operation that is slower than the second, it’s not clear why you are still asking questions about *parallel* Stream. Before your `main` method, the Stream API classes were not even loaded, not to speak of initialized, compiled, and/or optimized. It’s also possible that the regex classes were not used before. So you are measuring the time it takes to load, initialize, and compile/optimize a lot of classes.

Answer (score 0):

### Measuring performance

Measuring performance with Java is tricky.

Java uses a so-called "Hotspot" Just-In-Time compiler. It first starts the program in a non-optimized form, statistically monitors its execution, finds the CPU-consuming "hot spots" and optimizes them (of course, the real process is much more complex than this simplified explanation...).

So, any given piece of code will first run slowly and only after some repetition of the same code pattern, becomes faster. The JVM will not optimize your code during startup, only while executing it. That's why your `Thread.sleep()` didn't help, the optimization is only triggered by running some piece of code repeatedly.

Now you have three main code parts:

- the regular stream framework
- the parallel stream framework
- the "stream body" shared by both versions

and each of these three parts needs some warmup iterations until it gets its final performance.

If you start with the regular stream, then that will suffer from the non-optimized code plus the burden of optimizing both the regular-stream and the body part. Later repetitions of the regular stream already get a fully optimized environment and run full-speed.

If you then run a parallel stream, only the parallel-stream code still needs optimization, but it will profit from the optimized body that came from the regular stream execution.

**Rule of thumb:**

Measure the performance of any given piece of code only after it has repeatedly executed during a long-enough warmup phase.

### Improving performance

Use a profiler instead of guesswork.

Don't guess where your program is spending its time, get a measuring tool (called a "profiler") and let it tell you where you comsume CPU time. From 30+ years of software development, I can tell you that guesswork hardly ever finds the real bottlenecks.

You made some guesses on performance bottlenecks that turned out not to really tackle the problem.

It might well be the `Pattern.compile()` inside the stream body, as suggested by @Amongalen, but that's guesswork too. It might as well just be the `BufferedReader` for the file or simply waiting for the I/O. You can't know it before you measured it.